# vSphere Client上に構築した仮想マシンでGUIの操作ができない

Tags: centos, vmware

VMware Player上にVMware ESXi 5.5を構築し、vSphere Clientから仮想マシンを構築しました。CUIでキーボード操作する分には問題なく使えるのですが、GUIにした途端ちょっとしたボタン1つ押すことができません。

画面にカーソルは表示されています。

何とかこの環境でGUIでボタンを有効にする方法はないでしょうか？

ちなみにOSはCentOS7です。

Comment: まず確認するとしたら仮想マシンに十分なリソース (CPUやメモリ) が割り当てられているか、辺りからでしょうか。

Comment: その辺りが影響してくるんですね！知りませんでした。ひとまずミニマルインストールでメモリ1GB、ディスク10GBの状態で、後から拡張しようとしていました。ちなみにGUIはGNOMEを入れました。少なすぎますでしょうか？

Comment: [最小での推奨](https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product) は メモリ: 1GB になっていますが恐らくCUIベースで稼働させるサーバ用途向けかと思います。 / GNOME は比較的重いGUI環境なので、ホストに余裕があるなら割り当てを増やしてみてください。

Comment: わかりました！ありがとうございます！試してみます！

Comment: ダメでした…。メモリ4GB、CPU2つに変更してもまったく効きません。そーっとカーソルを近づけると白い手のアイコンから黒い矢印に変わるのでEnterを押すのですが、効きません。他にどのようなことが考えられるでしょうか？